# Create Map Tile Package (tpk) progress? arcpy.CreateMapTilePackage_management

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, tile-package

I'm using arcpy.CreateMapTilePackage_management to happily create a .tpk - all good.

Trouble is this can take a matter of hours, or days for a large complex mxd, once arcpy.CreateMapTilePackage_management has been called, is there any way of getting progress of how it's doing?

Comment: When you run this from it’s tool dialog what of its  progress gets reported in the Geoprocessing | Results window?  What parameter values are you using with it?  These can be obtained for easy reporting by using Copy As Python Snippet in the Geoprocessing | Results window.